# JavaScript: Public methods and prototypes

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, public-method

I'm not entirely sure how to implement OOP concepts in JS.

I have a class which is entirely declared in its constructor:

```
function AjaxList(settings)
{

    // all these vars are of dubious necessity... could probably just use `settings` directly
    var _jq_choice_selector = settings['choice_selector'];
    var _jq_chosen_list = settings['chosen_list'];
    var _cb_onRefresh = settings['on_refresh'];
    var _url_all_choices = settings['url_choices'];
    var _url_chosen = settings['url_chosen'];
    var _url_delete_format = settings['url_delete_format'];

    var jq_choice_selector_form = _jq_choice_selector.closest("form");
    if (DEBUG && jq_choice_selector_form.length != 1)
    {
        throw("There was an error selecting the form for the choice selector.");
    }

    function refresh()
    {
        _updateChoicesSelector();
        _updateChosenList();
        _cb_onRefresh();
    };

    AjaxList.prototype.refresh = refresh; // will this be called on all AjaxLists, or just the instance used to call it?
    // AjaxList.refresh = refresh; // will this be called on all AjaxLists, or just the instance used to call it?

    // ...
}
```

There are multiple instances of AjaxList. When I call `refresh()` on one of them, I want only that one list to refresh itself. In the following instance:

```
term_list = AjaxList(settings);
term_list.refresh();
```

The `refresh()` call seems to make all the AjaxLists refresh themselves. What is the correct way to do this?

I'm using jQuery, if it makes any difference.

Comment: you have some serious misconceptions about the language (javascript, jQuery, class). see my answer to see them clear.

Answer (score 7):

You should not redefine the prototype function in the constructor.
If you want to create a privileged function use this.methodname = ... from the constructor.

```
function AjaxList() {
  var privateVar = 0;
  function privateFunction() {
    //...
  }
  //create a refresh function just for this instance of the AjaxList
  this.refresh = function() {
    //privileged function, it can access the 'privateVar & privateFunction'
    privateVar++;
  }
}
//public functions that don't need access to the private variables/functions
AjaxList.prototype.publicFunction=function() {

};
```

Also if you want to create a proper object, you need to change

```
term_list = AjaxList(settings);
```

to

```
term_list = new AjaxList(settings);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
AjaxList = function(settings) {
    this._jq_choice_selector = settings["choice_selector"];
    this._jq_chosen_list = settings["chosen_list"];
    this._cb_onRefresh = settings["on_refresh"];
    this._url_all_choices = settings["url_choices"];
    this._url_chosen = settings["url_chosen"];
    this._url_delete_format = settings["url_delete_format"];

    this.jq_choice_selector_form = _jq_choice_selector.closest("form");
    if (DEBUG && jq_choice_selector_form.length != 1) {
        throw "There was an error selecting the form for the choice selector.";
    }
};

AjaxList.prototype = {
    _updateChoicesSelector: function() { },
    _updateChosenList: function() { },
    _cb_onRefresh: function() { },

    refresh: function() {
        this._updateChoicesSelector();
        this._updateChosenList();
        this._cb_onRefresh();
    }
};
```

Given that structure, you should be able to call:

```
var ajaxList = new AjaxList(settings);
ajaxList.refresh(); // etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using jQuery, if it makes any
>   difference.

No it doesn't. See my answer here: [**What's the difference between Javascript, Jquery and Ajax?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127938/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-jquery-and-ajax-programming/3133540#3133540)

> I have a class which is entirely
>   declared in its constructor

**There are no classes in Javascript**. Forget them. You really need to learn some of the basics of this language in order to use them. It's not Java, even though it looks similar.

If you have a ***Constructor Function*** it will create an instance. The ***shared methods*** will be in the ***prototype chain***, and only instance specific data goes right into the function with the ***this* keyword**.

So the basic concept of an object would look like this:

```
// constructor of an instance
function MyObject( param1, param2 ) {
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
  this.param3 = 32;
  return this; // [optional]
}

// Public methods can be called by any instance.
// Instances share their prototype object.
// The this keyword always points to the current
// instance that calls the method.
MyObject.prototype.sum = function() {
  return this.param1 + this.param2 + this.param3;
}

// refresh should be a shared method, since it
// does the same thing on every instance
MyObject.prototype.refresh = function() {
  // do the refresh
  // ...
}
```

The **power** of this concept is that there is **only one refresh function in memory**. And it can deal with any instance. In addition, if another object inherits from MyObject the **refresh function will be inherited**. But in the memory there will be still **one shared refresh function**. And it can deal with any of the parent or child instances.