# What is difference in JavaScript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 year of experience in ui devoloper and i have to sweech my compony,

SO when i attened 1st interview the interviewer ask me one question i.e.

In your application you use javascript or Jquery or both,so i am not give him a proper answer so please anyone give me the answer for this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283098/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: jQuery is a library written in javascript

Comment: jquery is a javascript library, that simplifies a programmer's life. jquery uses JavaScript behind the scene. Whatever code you want to write can be written in both Javascript and jquery however with jquery you will end writing less code compared to JavaScript and also you need not worry about cross browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript also known as `vanilla js` (like a joke). And pure js works faster than frameworks based on js.
There is a compartment of frameworks and pure js http://vanilla-js.com/. But using frameworks is easier than pure js.