# When to use $ in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a super newbie JS question, but am wondering how to use the '$' when writing JS.  For instance, I wrote a very simple JS if statement:

```
if (document.getElementById('D').value == '') {document.getElementById('D').value = 0;}
```

However, I saw someone else write it like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('D').value == '') {$('D').value = 0;}
```

Does '$' equal 'document.getElementById'?  What are best practices when using '$'?  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between JavaScript and jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283098/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: `$` is basically a identifier. In your second example, `$` is probably a reference to `jQuery` (a global function), being `jQuery` probably added by a library for JavaScript.

Comment: While `$` _usually_ refers to jQuery, it is possible for other libraries to use it (hence `jQuery.noConflict()`).  `$` is a valid variable, just like `document`.  Therefore, we can _assume_ `$('D')` is searching for a "D" element and returning it, but this doesn't really make sense in the context (personally, I've never heard of a "D" element).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of symbol $ in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery)

Comment: Research effort :)

Comment: @Someone - The second example is *not* jQuery (because jQuery objects don't have a `.value` property, and the argument is an element ID and not a CSS selector).

Comment: @c1moore Anyone who's read One Piece knows of the "D" element :)

Comment: @nnnnnn True, and the modern browsers have a global function called `$`, we just need to type $ in the console and test it (this global `$` looks like **`El#querySelector`**). The answer is wrong! Wrong as hell!

Comment: I think the second example could be wrong, anyway... if `$` may be a query selector probably, why wasn't a `'#'` declared before `'D'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ is usually used with JQuery. When you include JQuery in your page you can shorten references to it by using $('some css selector') to use it. If you didn't include JQuery you shouldn't need to use the $.

Here is a tutorial to get started with jquery: [W3Schools JQuery Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp).

They show some examples there.

Comment: w3schools is not necessarily a [good source](http://www.w3fools.com/) of information.  I typically suggest avoiding it (although it may have made improvements, W3Fools seems to suggest it still has mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

$ typically refers to [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). It is a widely used library that helps with DOM manipulation. Your second example would only work if you included jQuery in your project (or you defined $).

Comment: *"Your second example would only work if you included jQuery"* - The second example would *not* work with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The DOLLAR sign is shorthand for "jQuery".  Anyplace you want to use a jQuery function you can substitute "$" for  "jQuery".

... engage blithering idiot mode ...

I'm constantly referring to my copy of the O'Reilly jQuery Pocket Reference.  That plus the docs on the jQuery site and the users on StackExchange make life easier.  I still get tripped up when getting a single element from a jQuery function via brackets:

```
jQuery('div.topbar')[3]
```

That returns an HTML entity, not a jQuery object.

I use the debugger in Chrome a lot.  I can do a ton of prototyping and POCs in the debugger before committing the work to code.

Comment: *"The DOLLAR sign is shorthand for "jQuery""* - Except when it's not, e.g., if using MooTools or Prototype (or whatever). And not in the OP's example code either.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically used for the insertion of jQuery in your html code.