# Different ways to invoke functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some confusion regarding function invokes in javascript. there would be multiple ways to invoke a function on different contexts. Normally I have seen these 2 ways to invoke a function.

**Method 1:**

```
 $scope.test = function(){
       alert("function invoked");
 }();
```

**Method 2:**

```
 $scope.test = function(){
       alert("function invoked");
 }
 $scope.test();
```

However, I would like to know:

There is any difference in the following code with respect to performance?
Other criteria and in what context should I choose these?

I've gone through few of the blogs but couldn't understand it properly.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag?

Comment: **$** selector is of `Jquery`

Comment: @v́̎̈́̀̽̏̿̏͋—in jQuery, *$* is an identifier used to reference the jQuery function. The $ in *$scope* is simply a character in an identifier, it has no other meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There's a big difference.

The first example creates an anonymous function and sets `$scope.test` to the *return value* of that function.  Since the function doesn't return anything, method one sets `$scope.test` to `undefined`.

Method 2 actually sets `$scope.test` to a function and then calls it.

```js
var f1 = function(){ 
    alert("You'll see this right away!  the function is called directly after definition")
  }()

alert(f1)

var f2 = function(){
    alert("f2 has been called")
  }

alert("note, f2 hasn't been actually _called_ yet, just defined.");

f2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

These two are different. The first one will assign the return value of the function to `$scope.test`, while the second one will assign the definition of the function to `$scope.test`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a lot of people who would use Method 1 in normal cases. But this is how I see the differences between those two:

In Method 1, `$scope.test` stores the return value of the function invoked, which implicitly returns `undefined`, so `$scope.test` is `undefined`.

In Method 2, `$scope.test` actually stores a reference to the function and you can invoke it whenever you want using `$scope.test()`, but you cannot do the same with Method 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** is called, Anonymous function. Let’s look at another anonymous function:

```
(function() {
    alert('Hello World');
})();
```

Those last two parentheses are the self-executing part. They cause everything in the preceding parentheses to be executed immediately.

Let’s talk about [self-executing anonymous functions](http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write) inside and outside of objects:

```
(function() {
    var Person = {
        sayHello: function() {
            alert('Hello World');
        }
    }
})();
```

Here we have a self-executing anonymous function with an object inside of it that contains its own anonymous function.

> Note: It’s short for initializing. That name(`Person`) however, carries no special meaning.

**Method 2**, actually stores a reference to the function and you can invoke it later anytime you want.

Comment: They're both "anonymous" functions since neither has a name. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Few things; there is no [jQuery usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283098/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery) in this code you pasted.

In the first example you are executing an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) which do not have a return statement so you are assigning an `undefined` value to the `$scope.test` property.

In the second example you are assigning a function to the `$scope.test` property and then executing the function.

go check the MDN docs about [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) if still do you have any question go add a comment.