# What is the difference between the two javascript codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser

I am really curious.
I'm not sure what's the difference between these two codes.
I am very curious as a beginner in JavaScript
I would appreciate it if you kindly let me know.

```
$('#url' + nationId).on('click', function(){
    window.open(url);
})

document.getElementById('url' + nationId).setAttribute('onclick', "window.open(" + "'"+ url + "'" + ")");
```

Comment: [What is the difference between JavaScript and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283098/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: First is `jQuery` and Second is `JavaScript`. You can read more about in the above link :)