# Difference between js, jquery & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Guys I am just a beginner at javascript. I am really confused in between *JavaScript*, *JQuery* and *AJAX*. A little help will be appreciated. 
Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between AJAX with JavaScript and jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127938/what-is-the-difference-between-ajax-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: *Google*­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a core technologies of World Wide Web content production.
Jquery is a library built using Javascript to simplify your coding.
Ajax is a request made to a server asynchronously without reloading a page.(ajax can be implemented using both jquery and javascript)

Comment: Thank you bdy. I really appreciate. Now it is better than regular definitions.

Comment: Just one more confusion which one to use for web animation ?

Answer (score 0):

In one liners

1. JS is scripting language used by most of the browsers and Nodejs
2. JQuery is a framework/library(more appropriate) for JS
3. AJAX is a browser implementation to send HTTP request in background